# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to create a simple wordpress plugin that allows me to show the currently logged in User ID on a page by adding a shortcode.
I think I have it figured out for the biggest part, except that I'm getting a parse error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ';' or ',' in ... on line 53

Below it the code in which it fails

```
    function uniqueID_shortcode() {

    ob_start();
    
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    if($user_id == 0){
        echo '<span class="unique-id">No ID available because there is no logged in user. Please log in.</span>';
    }
    
    else{
        echo '<span class="unique-id">'.$user_id'</span>';
    }

    return ob_get_clean();

add_shortcode( 'show-unique-id', 'uniqueID_shortcode' );
```

Line 53 is

```
echo '<span class="unique-id">'.$user_id'</span>';
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you,
Kenneth

Comment: You're missing a `.` for the string concatenation to work, add a second `.` after `$user_id`.

Comment: echo '<span class="unique-id">'.$user_id'.</span>'; solved my issue. I was however also missing a } before my add_shortcode statement to close my function.